# How to check an email address for existence programmatically on Gmail?

Tags: email, gmail

If you google "How to check an email address for existence" question, you will find, basically, only solutions using SMTP protocol what is not reliable. I tried this approach and found that Gmail SMTP server says "Yes, this email is registered here" on each and every email address I ask about. I suspect such strategy is used on the majority of popular email servers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The method I would like to share is used in Gmail registration form to ensure you are going to register a brand new email. It uses AJAX request to ask Gmail server if given email exists or not

```
Request URL:https://accounts.google.com/InputValidator?resource=SignUp
Request Method:POST
Status Code:200 
Remote Address:173.194.222.84:443
```

### Response Headers

```
alt-svc:quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="37,36,35"
cache-control:private, max-age=0
content-encoding:gzip
content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8
date:Wed, 29 Mar 2017 21:06:06 GMT
expires:Wed, 29 Mar 2017 21:06:06 GMT
server:GSE
set-cookie:GAPS=1:<redacted>;Path=/;Expires=Fri, 29-Mar-2019 21:06:06 GMT;Secure;HttpOnly;Priority=HIGH
status:200
strict-transport-security:max-age=10893354; includeSubDomains
x-content-type-options:nosniff
x-frame-options:DENY
x-xss-protection:1; mode=block
```

### Request Headers

```
Provisional headers are shown
Content-type:application/json
Origin:https://accounts.google.com
Referer:https://accounts.google.com/SignUp?hl=en-GB
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36
```

### Query String Parameters

```
resource=SignUp
```

### Request Payload

```
{"input01":{"Input":"GmailAddress","GmailAddress":"andy.v.che","FirstName":"","LastName":""},"Locale":"en-GB"}
```

### Response

```
{"input01":{"Valid":"false","ErrorMessage":"Someone already has that username. Note that we ignore full stops and capitalisation in usernames. Try another?","Errors":{"GmailAddress":"Someone already has that username. Note that we ignore full stops and capitalisation in usernames. Try another?"},"ErrorData":["andyvche959"]},"Locale":"en_GB"}
```

As you can see, there is `"Valid":"false"` in the response if such an email does exist, and (spoilers) `"Valid":"true"` if it doesn't.

### Throttling queries down

Guys from Gmail do understand this method could be used by spammers to look for existing emails. That's why they don't allow massive scans using it. I was doing such a scan for some time and could scan only 200 emails a day approximately.

#### More details

I was scanning 1 email a minute, and if I was getting response "No, this email doesn't exist", I also asked if my own email exists. If I got "No, your email doesn't exist as well" answer, I could clearly understand that I got ban from Gmail server by my IP address. Then, I took a break for 45 minutes to get unbanned, then continued the loop. The number af emails scanned a day was fluctuating around 200.

You may ask: you did a scan like a spammer would perform, for what purpose did you do that scan then?

My answer is: I was trying to find a guy who wrote his email unclearly (bad cursive). There was no other option to find him.

There were 3 unclear letters in his written email but it was clear the domain of it is gmail.com, so I came up with an idea to find a way to check an email address for existence on Gmail, generate a list of all possible emails (trying to substitute unknown symbols with all possible English letters) and check them all for existence. Then, send a letter to all existing ones.

The right of this information to be published is discussed in [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/292855/answer-is-likely-to-be-used-for-objectionable-purposes) question. I understand this article will be very useful for spammers so I'm open to deleting it partially or even completely for the sake of security.